# Laravel mock multiple dependency

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit, php-pest

I have a Controller that has a dependency with BillingService, and BillingService has another dependency on UserService.

I need to call the Controller method **getPlans** and in this call I need to mock two functions:

- loadPlans that is inside BillingService
- getUsage that is in UserService

This is the full example:

```
class BillingPlanController
{
    public function __construct(private BillingPlanService $billingPlanService)
    {
    }

    public function getPlans()
    {
        $plans = $this->billingPlanService->getPlans();
        //
    }
}

class BillingPlanService
{
    public function __construct(private UserService $userService)
    {
    }

    public function getPlans()
    {
        $plans = $this->loadPlans();

        $user = auth()->user();
        $usage = $this->userService->getUsage(user); // DO SOMETHING, NEED TO MOCK .. HOW ?
    }

    public function loadPlans()
    {
        // DO SOMETHING, NEED TO MOCK .. HOW ?
    }
}
```

At the end, in my test i simply call:

```
getJson(action([BillingPlanController::class, "getPlans"]));
```

In other tests, I'm able to mock a single Service, but in this scenario, I don't know how to write the mocks.

Sorry if I don't provide any "tries", but I really don't know how I can do that.

**UPDATE**

I tried to use **partialMock** and **mock**, but I get this error (when getUsage is called) - **partialMock** is used because i just need to mock a single function:

```
Typed property App\Modules\Billing\Services\BillingPlanService::$userService must not be accessed before initialization

$this->mock(UserService::class, function ($mock) {
     $mock->shouldReceive("getUsage")->andReturn([]);
});

$this->partialMock(BillingPlanService::class, function ($mock) {
   $mock->shouldReceive("loadPlans")->andReturn([]);
});

getJson(action([BillingPlanController::class, "getPlans"]));
```

Comment: What happens if you mock both service fully and not partial?

Comment: I used partialMock on the first Service because the getPlans is the real function I need to test -  if i full mock him the function is not defined and i get: Received Mockery_3_App_Modules_Billing_Services_BillingPlanService::getPlans(), but no expectations were specified

I'm calling the controller because after this call, i need to test the response too. Its an integration test

Answer (score 1):

Your exception in your partial mock, is because when you mock the `BillingPlanService` you do not intilize the `userService` due to it being a mock. You can simply set it on the mock and i think it should work in your context.

```
$userServiceMock = $this->mock(UserService::class, function ($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive("getUsage")->andReturn([]);
});

$this->partialMock(BillingPlanService::class, function ($userServiceMock) use ($userServiceMock) {
    $mock->set('userService', $userServiceMock);
    $mock->shouldReceive("loadPlans")->andReturn([]);
});
```

Comment: The same :( using $mock->userService = $userServiceMock give the same error..

Comment: Using your solution (in this way works), i need to mark the UserService as public, but i would avoid to make this public...

Comment: I read the documentation and seems that maybe set can help,  try that if that won't help i will create an local example over the weekend and see what i can do. I'm guessing it is the combination of properties and it being partial. I have example code i have written thats sets properties thou on Mocks and not partials.

Comment: With public, it work as expected. But as i said, i think is bad mark the DI as public.. or at least i dont want it :) I continue to experiment and i wrote here if i found a solution. If you can too in WE, i really appreciate. The code i wrote you think is something "strange"? Have the DI as in my example ?

Comment: Your code is clean, didn't get the part with private property. There is some options to fake it to be public https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/5287312

Comment: oh.. this is a nice trick!